# chart size does not change after i mouse over it

Tags: javascript, jquery

in the following chart I want when I mouse over the size of the chart change with the following code:

```
var boxWidth = $("#chart").width();

    $("#chart").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).animate({
            width: "1500"
        });


    });
  $("#chart").mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).animate({
            width: boxWidth,


        });


    });
```

But as you see the only thing which is change is the background width and not the chart,here is the snippet:

https://dojo.telerik.com/onEBe

Comment: You need to redraw the chart once once you resize the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to reinitialize the chart.

```
$("#chart").mouseenter(function() {
  if ($(this).width() != 1000) {
    $(this).animate({
      width: "1000px"
    }, function() {
      createChart();
    });
  }


});
$("#chart").mouseleave(function() {
  if ($(this).width() != boxWidth) {
    $(this).animate({
      width: boxWidth
    }, function() {
      createChart();
    });
  }
});
```

Here I am checking the width because to recreate the chart only once on width change.

**Update:**

Instead of creating the chart again, just refresh it and it will take the width and height of the container.

```
$("#chart").data("kendoChart").refresh();
```

Comment: Thanks it works!but is the actual way I mean the proper way ?to achive such a thing?

Comment: @moris1983 check the updated answer. Refresh would do the job.

Answer (score -1):

You have to `createChart()` again to actually perform a refresh on the Chart.

```
    $("#chart").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).animate({
            width: "1500"
        });
        createChart();
    });
```

Comment: You will end up recreating charts forever. Also it should resize back on mouse out.

Comment: Yeah. True that. :)